# The current path, FirstApp/Challenge/{url 'FirstApp:Challenge1'}, didn't match any of these error

Tags: python, django, atom-editor

i have a challenge page to which pages challenge1 and challenge2 are linked but when i got to challenge page and try to access the challenge1 and challenge2 page i get following error
The current path, FirstApp/Challenge/{url 'FirstApp:Challenge1'}, didn't match any of these.

i have done similar things before but this one does not seem to be working ,can someone point out error and solution,please help

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Challenge</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>There are two challenges for you.</h2>

    <a href="{% url 'FirstApp:Challenge1' %}">Accept challenge1</a>
    =========================================================================<br>

   <a href="{% url 'FirstApp:Challenge2' %}">Accept challenge2.</a>
  </body>
</html>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Challenge 1</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   This is challenge 1. 


          <body>
</html>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Challenge 2</title>
  </head>
  <body>

this is challenge2.
        <body>
</html>

Views.py file
def Challenge2View(request):
    Challenge2Status= Challenge2.objects.filter(user=request.user)

    form=Challenge1Form()
    if request.method=="POST":
        form=Challenge1Form(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            return index(request)

        else:
            print("Invalid form")

    return render(request,'FirstApp/Challenge2.html',{'forms':form,'Challenge2Status':Challenge2Status})


def Challenge1View(request):
    Challenge1Status= Challenge1.objects.get(user=request.user)
    time=request.POST.get('Time')
    if time<=10:
        Challenge1Status.Hours_spent_learning+=time
        Challenge1Status.save()
    else:
        print("Time limit exceeded")


    return render(request,'FirstApp/Challenge1.html',{'Challenge1Status':Challenge1Status})


def ChallengeView(request):
    return render(request,'FirstApp/Challenge.html')

url.py application file
url(r'^Challenge/$',views.ChallengeView,name='Challenge'),
url(r'^Challenge1/$',views.Challenge1View,name='Challenge1'),
url(r'^Challenge2/$',views.Challenge2View,name='Challenge2'),
```

Comment: Likely this is located in the `FirstApp/Challenge.html`.

Comment: The `{% url %}` tags in your question look ok. The errors suggest you have `{ url ... }` (without the `%`). Check your project for any invalid tags, then restart `./manage runserver` and refresh your browser before clicking any links, to make sure you are running the latest version of your templates.

Comment: thanks Alasdair i made those{%%} change later and those were not being reflected,your suggestion worked.